# How can I delete ios folder in Flutter project?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm working on a project with Flutter and I accidently chose ios but I only need to work with Android, and now after my project has grown up, now I can't recreate a new project, so how can I delete ios from my current project, safely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing to worry about, just delete the `ios` directory, that's it!

In Flutter, every specific platform has a dedicated directory (ios, android, web, macos, windows, linux). Each directory uses the same code inside `lib` (Flutter, app-related code). Meaning, if you want to delete a specific platform, just delete a dedicated platform directory.

P.S. if you are using version control for your project, there is nothing to worry about - you can always revert your changes.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, you saved me.

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio.

Go to the project directory then, Right-click on the iOS folder then click on the delete option.

Note:- If want to recreate ios and android folder in a flutter.

**Just run this command in terminal:-**

```
flutter create.
```

[image: Refernce Android Screenshot]